# overloading >> operator inside class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What is the difference between the following ways to oveload the `>>` operator?

```
class A {
public:
    istream& operator>>(istream& is) { return is >> x; };
private:
    int x;
};

class B {
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, B b) { return is >> b.y; };
private:
    int y;
};
```

I can't use `std::cin >> a` but I can do `std::cin >> b`.

Isn't the first way a legit way to overload?

Comment: `operator>>(istream& is, B b)` will make a copy of the `B` object being streamed, which can grow expensive as you add more data members and/or bases (or become impossible if some of those can't be copied).  It's much better to use `operator>>(istream& is, const B& b)` so you access the `B` value stipulated by the caller *in place*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do an in-member overload of an operator, then the left-hand-side of that operator is an instance of the class.

For example, with your `A` class:

```
A a;
a >> std::cin;  // Calls a.operator>>(std::cin)
```

---

When you declare the `friend` function for class `B`, it's not a member function but a non-member function. It's basically the same as doing

```
class B {
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, B b);  // Just declare the function
private:
    int y;
};

// Here's the function definition
istream& operator>>(istream& is, B b) { return is >> b.y; };
```

With this function, the left-hand-side is passed as the first argument, and the right-hand-side is passed as the second argument.

Which means

```
B b;
std::cin >> b;  // Equal to operator>>(std::cin, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the first one isn't "legit" because normally you want `>>` to take an `istream` as its left-hand-side argument, but your member function takes `A` as its left-hand-side argument (as `this`), which means you can't call `std::cin >> a`, but you can call `a >> std::cin` which doesn't make much sense.